# UWP GridView get number of items in row

Tags: c#, gridview, navigation, uwp

I have a `GridView` in c# UWP, that has some items in it (let's say, its filled up with 100 items). I want the `GridView` to support the arrow-keys on the keyboard. In order to select the item above my current item, I need to know how many items are in one row.

How do I get the number of items in a row?

Comment: Are all items of same size or are they sized dynamically? If they are fixed size, you can take `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` of selected item and devide the size of `GridView` with size of item, this should give you the number of how many items can fit. This will also give you info on which position the selected item is.

Comment: the size of each item is fixed and I thought about the approach with `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` too. But I would prefer a dynamic approach, as it is more universal and the width of each item might be dynamic in near future.

Comment: I searched a little as it's weird to me too that there is no property for that. Everyone is saying that you can't determine the number of items in row straight away because the control is placing items dynamically depending on the size. You can get the total number of elements in grid and order of elements no problem. When you do implement dynamically sized items, you could just iterate through them, measure sizes and calculate items count using that info, that way you would get the number of items in each row. You would need to do this calculation every time grid size changes though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Well then it has to be that way, even thou it's quite a strange approach to it that way.